# Unexpected behaviour of PowerSpectralDensity

Tags: fourier-analysis

I recently wanted to calculate the power spectral density of a surface profile. I was happy to find out that there is a built in PowerSpectralDensity[] function in Mathematica (version 10). However, I'm surprised to find the following behaviour:

```
straightline = Range[1, 10, 0.2];
Plot[PowerSpectralDensity[straightline, w], {w, 0.1, 10}]
```

gives:

[image]

Note that 2Pi=6.28. Now, from my very faint recollection of University classes, I assumed this should be flat or at least similar to

```
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[straightline]]^2]
```

Why is it not? Why do we get this result?

It probably has to do with the window function `w` since `2w` moves the position of the peak by a factor of 1/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same, sort of. You can make PowerSpectralDensity and Fourier show the same plot:

```
straightline = Range[1, 10, 0.2];
straightline = straightline - Mean[straightline];
ListPlot[Table[PowerSpectralDensity[straightline, w], 
         {w, 0, 2 Pi-0.001, 2 Pi/Length[straightline]}], PlotRange -> All]

ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[straightline]]^2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The main difference is that the PowerSpectralDensity (PSD) is reported as a (continuous-valued) function of frequency, while Fourier just calculates samples of this function. So to make the plots the same, we need to sample the PSD at the same points. A minor difference is that the PSD more or less assumes a zero mean signal, so to make them match, the code above removes the DC/constant term. Outside of {0,2 Pi}, both functions repeat with period 2 Pi, which in this case, is the complete list of 40-some points.

Comment: thanks bill. Why did you exclude the 2Pi datapoint?

Comment: The zero point and the 2 Pi point are the same, due to the periodicity, so it seemed cleaner to remove it.